# How to adjust the arrow icon in a dropdown menu when the user clicks outside in angular?

Tags: angular, drop-down-menu, dropdown, ng-class

How to control the icon direction when click outside (empty space)?
-fa-angle-up when the user open the dropdown

-fa-angle-down when the user close/default the dropdown

[here is stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vnxfyq?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In template you could use `blur` listener, so when focus goes away from element (e.g clicking outside) it would turn the flag.

```html
(blur)="menuExpandCategory = !menuExpandCategory"
```

Forked: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-v6heew?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html